# Resize ImageView by Picasso with ConstraintLayout bug

Tags: android, picasso, android-constraintlayout

I have a problem with my layout responsiveness, issue is connected with Picasso image resizing. My empty template (without using Picasso and inserting image into view) look like below:
[image: Before load]

When Picasso starts to load my image to middle view, it adjust bounds (while resizing and loading I can see white space) like below:

[image: While loading]

After image is downloaded and resized it resize constraints, finally it looks like this:
[image]

Picasso left free space between constraints, because chain is set to spread-inside - and this part is ok ( when I change it to packed I have the same space but on top and bottom) I just don't want this free space generated by picasso. Is there any trick to avoid this and achieve something like this? Maybe I did something wrong ?

[image: What I want to achieve]

I can't set height statically because I am loading images dynamically and I don't know their dimensions.

I've tried many options and hacks, but without success.

Source code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/topWrapper"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/middleLayoutImage"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside">

        (... not important code int his case ...) 

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/middleLayoutImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/middleLayoutText"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topWrapper"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/middleLayoutText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/middleLayoutImage"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"/>

    (... not important code int his case ...)

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Picasso code:

```
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) constraintLayout.findViewById(R.id.middleLayoutImage);
    Picasso.with(imageView.getContext())
            .load(pictureLink)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.load_pixel)
            .fit()
            .centerInside()
            .into(imageView);
```

Thanks for help in advince.

Answer (score 0):

try this if it helps

```
Picasso  
.with(context)
.load(imageurl)
.resize(600, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). does not respect aspect ratio
.into(imageViewResize);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Packed` linear groups of `ConstraintLayout`.

**Note:Set TopAlign to your whole chain to placed at top.**

Here is the Code:

**JAVA**

```
Picasso.with(this).load(inputurl).into(iv);
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="md.com.application_initial.PicassoCheck"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_picasso_check">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/topWrapper"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#d3d3d3"
    android:padding="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/middleLayoutImage"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Top Constraint Layout" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/middleLayoutImage"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#f3f3f3"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/middleLayoutText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topWrapper"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/middleLayoutText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#d3d3d3"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/middleLayoutImage"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />
```

Layout before load:

[image]

**OUTPUT**

[image]

More about Chained behaviour https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb

See also Official Page https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-chain

Answer (score 0):

> I have set the imageview height and width as per device ratio, and
>   use the glide to load image.
>
> add imageview in layout file

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
```

> copy following code in class file

```
private void displayImage()
{
    if (!theImagePath.isEmpty()) {
                imageViewScanBusinessCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                Point size = new Point();
                display.getSize(size);
                int width = size.x - 10;
                imageViewScanBusinessCard.getLayoutParams().height = width / 2;
                imageViewScanBusinessCard.getLayoutParams().width = width;
                imageViewScanBusinessCard.requestLayout();

                File file = new File(theImagePath);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    loadImageWithGlide(this, imageView,
                            theImagePath);
                }
            }
}

    public static void loadImageWithGlide(Context theCtx, ImageView theImageView, String theUrl) {
        Glide.with(theCtx)
                .load(theUrl)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(theImageView);
    }
```

> Add dependency in app gradle

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```